# When doing a t-test for the significance of a regression coefficient, why is the number of degrees of freedom $n-p-1$?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, multiple-regression, t-test

I read [here](http://www.unesco.org/webworld/idams/advguide/Chapt5_2.htm) that $n-p-1$ was the number of degrees of freedom I should use when doing a t-test for the significance of a regression coefficient, but I don't understand why. My understanding was that t-tests generally had $n-1$ degrees of freedom.

Comment: Typically the number of parameters is ``p+1`` since there are ``p`` slopes and ``1`` intercept.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You lose one degree of freedom for each estimated mean parameter. For an ordinary t-test that's 1 (the mean). For regression, each predictor costs you a degree of freedom. The extra one is for the intercept.

More specifically, the degrees of freedom come from the denominator in the t-test, which is based on the residual sum of squares -- there are $n-p-1$ degrees of freedom in the residual sums of squares.

Comment: In fact if you regress some outcome on  a constant (only an intercept in the model) you get the mean, p would then be 0, and one would have n-1 degrees of freedom

Answer (score 3):

This is not true in general. The number of degrees of freedom of t-test depends on a specific model. They're talking about linear regression. So, t-test for an estimator has $n-p-1$ degrees of freedom where $p$ is number of explanatory parameters in the model.

Answer (score 1):

Degrees of freedom is the number of independent values or quantities which can be assigned to a statistical distribution.

So in this case its n−p−1 because:

n is number of training samples.
p is number of predictors.
1 is for intercept.