# Proof that the coefficients in an OLS model follow a t-distribution with (n-k) degrees of freedom

Tags: regression, linear-model, least-squares, t-distribution

## Background

Suppose we have an Ordinary Least Squares model where we have $k$ coefficients in our regression model,
$$\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{X}\mathbf{\beta} + \mathbf{\epsilon}$$

where $\mathbf{\beta}$ is an $(k\times1)$ vector of coefficients, $\mathbf{X}$ is the *design matrix* defined by

$$\mathbf{X} = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & x_{11} & x_{12} & \dots & x_{1\;(k-1)} \\
1 & x_{21} & \dots  &       &   \vdots \\
\vdots &   & \ddots &       &   \vdots \\
1 & x_{n1} & \dots  & \dots &   x_{n\;(k-1)}    
\end{pmatrix}$$
and the errors are IID normal, 
$$\mathbf{\epsilon} \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\mathbf{0},\sigma^2 \mathbf{I}\right) \;.$$

We minimize the sum-of-squared-errors by setting our estimates for $\mathbf{\beta}$ to be
$$\mathbf{\hat{\beta}}= (\mathbf{X^T X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{y}\;. $$

An unbiased estimator of $\sigma^2$ is 
$$s^2 = \frac{\left\Vert \mathbf{y}-\mathbf{\hat{y}}\right\Vert ^2}{n-p}$$
where $\mathbf{\hat{y}} \equiv \mathbf{X} \mathbf{\hat{\beta}}$ ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Estimation)).

The covariance of $\mathbf{\hat{\beta}}$ is given by
$$\operatorname{Cov}\left(\mathbf{\hat{\beta}}\right) = \sigma^2 \mathbf{C}$$
where $\mathbf{C}\equiv(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X})^{-1}$ ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Finite_sample_properties)) .

## Question

How can I prove that for $\hat\beta_i$,
$$\frac{\hat{\beta}_i - \beta_i} {s_{\hat{\beta}_i}} \sim t_{n-k}$$
where $t_{n-k}$ is a t-distribution with $(n-k)$ degrees of freedom, and the standard error of $\hat{\beta}_i$ is estimated by $s_{\hat{\beta}_i} = s\sqrt{c_{ii}}$.

---

## My attempts

I know that for $n$ random variables sampled from $x\sim\mathcal{N}\left(\mu, \sigma^2\right)$, you can show that 
$$\frac{\bar{x}-\mu}{s/\sqrt{n}} \sim t_{n-1} $$
by rewriting the LHS as
$$\frac{ \left(\frac{\bar x - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}\right)  }  
{\sqrt{s^2/\sigma^2}}$$
and realizing that the numertor is a standard normal distribution, and the denominator is square root of a Chi-square distribution with df=(n-1) and divided by (n-1) ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution#Applications)).  And therefore it follows a t-distribution with df=(n-1) ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution#As_the_distribution_of_a_test_statistic)).

I was unable to extend this proof to my question...

Any ideas?  I'm aware of [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/93130/when-doing-a-t-test-for-the-significance-of-a-regression-coefficient-why-is-the), but they don't explicitly prove it, they just give a rule of thumb, saying "each predictor costs you a degree of freedom".

Comment: Because $\hat\beta_i$ is a linear combination of jointly Normal variables, it has a Normal distribution. Therefore *all* you need do are (1) establish that $\mathbb{E}(\hat\beta_i)=\beta_i$; (2) show that $s_{\hat\beta_i}^2$ is an unbiased estimator of $\text{Var}(\hat\beta_i)$; and (3) demonstrate the degrees of freedom in $s_{\hat\beta_i}$ is $n-k$.  The latter has been proven on this site in several places, such as http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/16931. I suspect you already know how to do (1) and (2).

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Since
$$\begin{align*}
\hat\beta &= (X^TX)^{-1}X^TY \\
&= (X^TX)^{-1}X^T(X\beta + \varepsilon) \\
&= \beta + (X^TX)^{-1}X^T\varepsilon
\end{align*}$$
we know that
$$\hat\beta-\beta \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2 (X^TX)^{-1})$$
and thus we know that for each component $k$ of $\hat\beta$,
$$\hat\beta_k -\beta_k \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2 S_{kk})$$
where $S_{kk}$ is the $k^\text{th}$ diagonal element of $(X^TX)^{-1}$.
Thus, we know that 
$$z_k = \frac{\hat\beta_k -\beta_k}{\sqrt{\sigma^2 S_{kk}}} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1).$$

Take note of the statement of the *Theorem for the Distribution of an Idempotent Quadratic Form in a Standard Normal Vector* (Theorem B.8 in Greene):

> If $x\sim\mathcal{N}(0,I)$ and $A$ is symmetric and idempotent, then $x^TAx$ is distributed $\chi^2_{\nu}$ where $\nu$ is the rank of $A$.

Let $\hat\varepsilon$ denote the regression residual vector and let 
$$M=I_n - X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T \text{,}$$
which is the residual maker matrix (i.e. $My=\hat\varepsilon$). It's easy to verify that **$M$ is symmetric and idempotent**.

Let
$$s^2 = \frac{\hat\varepsilon^T \hat\varepsilon}{n-p}$$
be an estimator for $\sigma^2$.

We then need to do some linear algebra. Note these three linear algebra properties:

- The rank of an idempotent matrix is its trace.
- $\operatorname{Tr}(A_1+A_2) = \operatorname{Tr}(A_1) + \operatorname{Tr}(A_2)$
- $\operatorname{Tr}(A_1A_2) = \operatorname{Tr}(A_2A_1)$ if $A_1$ is $n_1 \times n_2$ and $A_2$ is $n_2 \times n_1$ (**this property is critical for the below to work**)

So 
$$\begin{align*}
\operatorname{rank}(M) = \operatorname{Tr}(M) &= \operatorname{Tr}(I_n - X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T) \\
&= \operatorname{Tr}(I_n) - \operatorname{Tr}\left( X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T) \right) \\
&= \operatorname{Tr}(I_n) - \operatorname{Tr}\left( (X^TX)^{-1}X^TX) \right) \\
&= \operatorname{Tr}(I_n) - \operatorname{Tr}(I_p) \\
&=n-p
\end{align*}$$

Then 
$$\begin{align*}
V = \frac{(n-p)s^2}{\sigma^2} = \frac{\hat\varepsilon^T\hat\varepsilon}{\sigma^2} = \left(\frac{\varepsilon}{\sigma}\right)^T M \left(\frac{\varepsilon}{\sigma}\right).
\end{align*}$$

Applying the Theorem for the Distribution of an Idempotent Quadratic Form in a Standard Normal Vector (stated above), we know that $V \sim \chi^2_{n-p}$.

Since you assumed that $\varepsilon$ is normally distributed, then $\hat\beta$ is independent of $\hat\varepsilon$, and since $s^2$ is a function of $\hat\varepsilon$, then $s^2$ is also independent of $\hat\beta$. Thus, $z_k$ and $V$ are independent of each other.

Then,
$$\begin{align*}
t_k = \frac{z_k}{\sqrt{V/(n-p)}}
\end{align*}$$
is the ratio of a standard Normal distribution with the square root of a Chi-squared distribution with the same degrees of freedom (i.e. $n-p$), which is a characterization of the $t$ distribution. **Therefore, the statistic $t_k$ has a $t$ distribution with $n-p$ degrees of freedom.**

It can then be algebraically manipulated into a more familiar form.

$$\begin{align*}
t_k &= \frac{\frac{\hat\beta_k -\beta_k}{\sqrt{\sigma^2 S_{kk}}}}{\sqrt{\frac{(n-p)s^2}{\sigma^2}/(n-p)}} \\
&= \frac{\frac{\hat\beta_k -\beta_k}{\sqrt{S_{kk}}}}{\sqrt{s^2}} = \frac{\hat\beta_k -\beta_k}{\sqrt{s^2 S_{kk}}} \\
&= \frac{\hat\beta_k -\beta_k}{\operatorname{se}\left(\hat\beta_k \right)}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Also a side question: for the `Theorem for the Distribution of an Idempotent Quadratic Form in a Standard Normal Vector`, don't we also need $A$ to be symmetric?  Unfortunately, I don't have Greene, so I can't see the proof although I saw that [Wikipedia had the same form as you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution#Relation_to_other_distributions).  However, a counter example seems to be the idempotent matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ which leads to $x_1^2+x_1 x_2$ which is not Chi-Squared since it could take on negative values...

Comment: @Garrett My apologies, $A$ should be both symmetric and idempotent. A proof is provided as Theorem 3 in this document: http://www2.econ.iastate.edu/classes/econ671/hallam/documents/QUAD_NORM.pdf Luckily, $M$ is symmetric as well as idempotent.

Comment: $A$ is merely *a* matrix representation of a quadratic form. Every quadratic form has a symmetric representation, so the requirement of symmetry of $A$ is implicit in the statement of the theorem. (People do not use asymmetric matrices to represent quadratic forms.)  Thus the quadratic form $(x_1,x_2)\to x_1^2+x_1x_2$ is uniquely represented by the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1/2\\1/2&0\end{pmatrix}$ which is *not* idempotent.

Comment: this is a great explanation for nonrandom x. Can you explain the deriviation if x is assumed to be random?

Comment: Why does $\epsilon\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ imply $\hat{\beta}$ is independent of $\hat{\epsilon}$? Not quite following there.

Comment: @Glassjawed As both $\hat{\beta}$ and $\hat{\varepsilon}$ are multivariate normally distributed, then uncorrelatedness implies independence. Using expressions $\hat{\beta} = \beta + \left(X^{\top}X\right)^{-1}X^{\top}\varepsilon$ and $\hat{\varepsilon} = M\varepsilon$ from above, we can show that $\operatorname{Cov}\left(\hat{\beta}, \hat{\varepsilon}\right) = \mathbf{0}_{p\times n}$.

Comment: Why is this line;
\begin{align*}
V = \frac{(n-p)s^2}{\sigma^2} = \frac{\hat\varepsilon^T\hat\varepsilon}{\sigma^2} = \left(\frac{\varepsilon}{\sigma}\right)^T M \left(\frac{\varepsilon}{\sigma}\right).
\end{align*}
And not:
\begin{align*}
V = \frac{(n-p)s^2}{\sigma^2} = \frac{\hat\varepsilon^T\hat\varepsilon}{\sigma^2} = \left(\frac{y}{\sigma}\right)^T M \left(\frac{y}{\sigma}\right).
\end{align*}
If $My=\hat\varepsilon$?

Comment: A text I went through argued on pg 21 that the coefficients are multivariate normally distributed rather than t-distributed? What is causing the discrepancy here http://home.cc.umanitoba.ca/~godwinrt/4042/material/part3.pdf