Manual specification of knots vs bs() for Piecewise regression
I am learning how to specify and plot piecewise regressions and have encountered a confusing situation. Namely, I have specified the knot for a piecewise regression using 2 methods: (1) manual and (2) using the bs() function from library(splines). There are 2 grounds of confusion:

both methods provide completely different sets of coefficients
both methods when specified in the formula argument of geom_smooth(method = lm, formula = ...) for a ggplot() provides the same smooth line

See charts below:

Why do these two methods produce different coefficients? How can 2 models with different coefficients churn out the same geom_smooth line in ggplot()?
Intuitively, I know that the manual specification is correct. However, I would like to understand what is going on here so I can better utilise the bs() function in the future for specifying piecewise models.
Code for data and model:
> data_ship
    Cost Parts
1  11.95   225
2  14.13   350
3   8.93   150
4  10.98   200
5  10.03   175
6  10.13   180
7  13.75   325
8  13.30   290
9  15.00   400
10  7.97   125

> # manual method
> lm(Cost ~ Parts + I((Parts - 250)* (Parts >= 250)), data_ship)$coef
                  (Intercept)                             Parts I((Parts - 250) * (Parts >= 250)) 
                   3.21392570                        0.03845992                       -0.02477335 
> 
> # bs() method
> lm(Cost ~ bs(Parts, knots = c(250), degree = 1), data_ship)$coef
                           (Intercept) bs(Parts, knots = c(250), degree = 1)1 bs(Parts, knots = c(250), degree = 1)2 
                              8.021416                               4.807491                               6.860476 


Code for chart:
# 1. manual method
coef.manual <- lm(Cost ~ Parts + I((Parts - 250)* (Parts >= 250)), data_ship)$coef
coef.manual <- signif(coef.manual, 5)

fx.manual <- bquote(Cost == .(coef.manual[1]) + .(coef.manual[2])~ Parts - 
                      .(abs(coef.manual[3]))(Parts - 250)~X[1])

library(ggplot2)

plt.1 <- 
  ggplot(data_ship, aes(x = Parts, y = Cost)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, formula = y ~ x + I((x - 250)* (x >= 250)),
              colour = "firebrick2", se = F) +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, colour = "firebrick4", linetype = "dashed", se = F) +
  labs(title = "Fitted line plot", subtitle = fx.manual,
       y = "Cost (in $1000)", 
       caption = "formula = y ~ x + I((x - 250)* (x >= 250))")


# 2. bs() method
library(splines)

coef.bs <- lm(Cost ~ bs(Parts, knots = c(250), degree = 1), data_ship)$coef
coef.bs <- signif(coef.bs, 5)

fx.bs <- bquote(Cost == .(coef.bs[1]) + .(coef.bs[2])~ Parts - 
                  .(abs(coef.bs[3]))(Parts - 250)~X[1])

plt.2 <-
  ggplot(data_ship, aes(x = Parts, y = Cost)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, formula = y ~ bs(x, knots = c(250), degree = 1),
              colour = "firebrick2", se = F) +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, colour = "firebrick4", linetype = "dashed", se = F) +
  labs(title = "Fitted line plot", subtitle = fx.bs,
       y = "Cost (in $1000)", 
       caption = "formula = y ~ bs(x, knots = c(250), degree = 1)")


# 3. compile plots
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

grid.arrange(plt.1, plt.2, nrow = 1)

My heartfelt apologies if this seems "basic"

https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/639701/11849

@Roland thank you so much for the link to the discussion, I shall take my time to digest what was discussed there

When you set the knot manually, you implicitly started with an intercept at a Parts value of 0. I think that bs() implicitly started with an intercept at the minimum of the values of Parts in your data set, 125. Note that your manual model predicts a Cost value of 8.02 at Parts=125, identical to the "Intercept" in the equation provided by bs(). Although I haven't worked it through, I suspect that the difference in the other coefficients are related to the difference in the choice of intercept location in the two methods.
In general, recognize that different implementations of splines can use different basis functions, so that coefficients aren't generally comparable across implementations. As in your situation, however, once the coefficients are applied to the correct basis functions, predictions should be the same. Chapter 2 of Frank Harrell's Regression Modeling Strategies goes into some detail, an provides links for further study. Note that results with your piecewise linear spline approach will probably depend heavily on your choice of knot position. Unless you have strong theoretical reason to believe that there is such a discontinuity in slope, you are generally better off using a cubic regression spline, explained in that reference, and letting the data tell you the slope of the association.

First, thank you for your prompt response. I'm unsure of whether the way bs() arrives at its intercept value is the issue. Just looking at its coefficients, it just appears wrong.
For example, at Parts = 200, i should get Cost = 11. Its geom_smooth() is correct, but it appears to be incoherent with its coefficients. That is, presuming that I have specified the regression function of bs() correctly in fx.bs

@Yat-Hon the coefficients reported by the bs() model, unlike those of the manual model, are NOT with respect to Parts values themselves. They are with respect to the two internal basis functions used by bs() here: bs(Parts, knots = c(250), degree = 1)1 and bs(Parts, knots = c(250), degree = 1)2. You cannot just plug in values of Parts with those coefficients from bs() (as your labeling on the right panel and your comment suggest that you are doing). Those coefficients only work with the basis functions. This is one example of the general problem noted in my second paragraph.

is it correct to say that the bs() coefficients represents the y-axis value for their respective knots (which are the x-axis values) such that the coefficients c(8.0214, 4.8075, 6.805) represents the following (x, y) coordinates: (min(data_ship$Parts), 8.0214 + 0), (250, 8.0214 + 4.8075), (max(data_ship$Parts), 8.0214 + 6.8605). Where default boundary knot values for bs() are c(min(x), max(x))

@Yat-Hon that might be correct but I'm afraid that my head starts to hurt whenever I think too hard about basis functions for splines. A recent comment on your question, and the Harrell reference in this answer (and its links) should point you to more complete information.
