# Understanding sum of square deviations

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, mean, random-variable

Given $X_1...X_n\stackrel{iid}{\sim} N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and  $U=\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\overline{X})^2$,
why is $U\sim\sigma^2 \chi_{n-1}^2$ ?

And what would be the distribution of $V=\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\mu)^2$ ?

Comment: $X_i$ are independent right? And also, is this a self-study question? If so, please add a tag.

Comment: yeah, sorry. fixed it

Comment: Hint: $X_1-\mu, X_2-\mu, \ldots, X_n-\mu$ are iid $N(0,\sigma^2)$ random variables.  What does your book have to say about this distribution? Nothing? How about considering $(X_1-\mu)/\sigma, (X_2-\mu)/\sigma, \ldots, (X_n-\mu)/\sigma$ which are iid $N(0,1)$ random variables?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/385032/residual-sum-of-squares-degrees-of-freedom-intuition and the links posted there.