# How to estimate $\hat{\rho}_{t_{1},t_{2}}$ in $F$ statistic expressed in terms of $t$ statistics with two restrictions?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, multiple-regression

I'm studying Econometrics from [Stock and Watson](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/935286350X), and when mentioning the F-statistic in the Multiple Regression (Chapter 7), there is this formula:

[image]

How can I estimate $\hat{\rho}_{t_{1},t_{2}}?$ Can I use the correlation coefficient between the two variables?

I suppose there is a standard formula used for the statistical softwares, but I could not find.

Comment: While SW's exposition makes pedogogical sense to discuss how the F test works, you do not really need to estimate this expression - I believe it is more fruitful to proceed from the general expression of the F statistic directly, as discussed e.g. here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/258461/proof-that-f-statistic-follows-f-distribution/258476#258476

Comment: See also the page from Christoph Hanck's [book](https://www.econometrics-with-r.org/7-3-joint-hypothesis-testing-using-the-f-statistic.html).

Comment: @ChristophHanck, to be frank, we were never bothered with expressing the F statistic in terms of individual $t$ statistic. Even though the authors provided a heuristic argument, they didn't provide a derivation. Are there any derivation in the same vein? I didn't didn't find any other books expressing the F statistic in this way.

Comment: I have been pushing around the expression for the F statistic for a bit but have also not obtained something which would exactly match S&W's (7.9) so far...

Comment: @ChristophHanck do we need this expression to construct the confidence set mentioned in the same section of the book?

Comment: No, as I suggested, we can work with a general expression for the F statistic. S&W's expression is just an alternative way to write the statistic (albeit one we do not understand atm :-) )