Is it possible to conduct an F test without fitting a restricted model?
Say I'm fitting the following regression:
$$
Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_1 + \beta_2X_2 + \beta_3X_3 + \beta_4X_4
$$
If I was interested in testing the hypothesis that $\beta_2 = 0$, I know I can do things:

I could fit a regression dropping the $\beta_2X_2$ term and compare the RSS from the full and restricted model through an F test.
Or I could use the estimate and standard error for $\beta_2$ and use a t-test to assess the probability that the hypothesis is true.

Now, say that instead I want to test multiple hypotheses, eg. that $\beta_2=0$ and $\beta_3=\beta_4$. In this case, I know I can proceed by doing #1 (fitting a restricted model under the hypothesis and conducting an F-test), but I'm wondering if there is an analog for #2 in the multiple hypothesis case.
In other words, I essentially want to know whether I can test the hypothesis that $\beta_2 = 0$ and $\beta_3 = \beta_4$ using only the beta estimates and variance covariance matrix from the full model (rather than fitting a restricted model).
Thanks so much!

Yes: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/258461/prove-that-f-statistic-follows-f-distribution/258476#258476

Sounds like a job for a Wald test with a suitably chosen $\mathbf{R}$.

Thanks so much!

FWIW, the test does not determine "the probability that the hypothesis is true."  We have many posts here on CV that discuss the interpretation of such tests.
