F-test in simple linear regression
I'm trying to understand the F-test for the effectiveness of the simple linear regression (SLR) model but I have a few questions regarding it :

Why do we divide the SSR by the number of independent variables (1 for SLR) and the SSE by the number of degrees of freedom (n-2 for SLR)? Why not divide both by the number of independent variables so that we can calculate the average explained/unexplained variability corresponding to the independent variable?

How is the test-statistic F-distributed under the null hypothesis that $\beta_1 = 0$?



Because these turn out to be the scalings we need in order to get the appropriate F-distribution: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/258461/prove-that-f-statistic-follows-f-distribution/258476#258476

A piece of this question that confuses me is that it starts out mentioning simple linear regression but then alludes to multiple independent variables. Could you please clarify?

My apologies. I referred to the general formula for the F-test but I specifically only need an answer for the simple linear regression case. I will edit the question to clarify the same.

The F distribution is the distribution of $\left( \chi^2/\text{df} \right) / \left( \chi^2/\text{df} \right)$ where the two chi-square random variables are independent of each other, and $“\text{ df }”$ is the appropriate number of degrees of freedom for each (the two $“\text{ df ”s}$ are two different numbers).
The chi-square distribution with $k$ degrees of freedom is the distribution of the sum of $k$ independent standard normal random variables.
Let $\widehat\beta$ be the least-squares estimate of the slope in a simple linear regression problem. Assume the errors are independent and normally distributed with expectation $0$ and variance $\sigma^2.$
The errors are $\varepsilon_i = y_i - (\alpha+\beta x_i)$ for $i=1,\ldots,n.$ The residuals are observable estimates of the unobservable errors; they are $y_i - \left( \widehat\alpha + \widehat\beta x_i \right)$ for $i = 1,\ldots,n.$
So we have $\displaystyle \frac{\varepsilon_1^2 + \cdots + \varepsilon_n^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \chi^2_n.$
Now the hard part: $\displaystyle \frac{\widehat\varepsilon_1^2 + \cdots + \widehat\varepsilon_n}{\sigma^2} \sim \chi^2_{n-2}.$
Why should the sum of squares of residuals have that distribution when (1) there are $n$ of then, not $n-2,$ and (2) they are not independent, since they satisfy the two linear constraints, $\widehat\varepsilon_1+\cdots + \widehat\varepsilon_n = 0$ and $\widehat\varepsilon_1 x_1 +\cdots + \widehat\varepsilon_n x_n = 0,$ and (3) they have variances differing from $\sigma^2.$
I think that question has been answered in detail here before, and the answer may be long, and I will not answer it here.
From $$ \widehat\beta \sim \operatorname N\left( \beta, \frac{\sigma^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \overline x)^2} \right), \tag 1 $$ we get $$ \left( \frac{\widehat\beta - \beta}{\sigma\left/\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \overline x)^2 } \right. } \right)^2 \sim \chi^2_1. $$
But why is the quantity on line (1) independent of the residuals? That would also require a longer answer than I can write now, and that's probably been done here before as well.
Now look again at the first sentence in this answer. (And note that the $\sigma^2$ cancels out, which is fortunate since it is not observable.)
