# Why is a T distribution used for hypothesis testing a linear regression coefficient?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, linear-model, t-distribution

In practice, using a standard T-test to check the significance of a linear regression coefficient is common practice. The mechanics of the calculation make sense to me.

Why is it that the T-distribution can be used to model the standard test statistic used in linear regression hypothesis testing? Standard test statistic I am referring to here:

$$
T_{0} = \frac{\widehat{\beta} - \beta_{0}}{SE(\widehat{\beta})}
$$

Comment: A full and complete answer to this question will be quite long, I'm sure.  So while you wait for someone to tackle this, you can get a pretty good idea of why this is the case by looking at some notes I found online here:  https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat501/node/297.  Note specifically that $t^2_{(n−p)}=F_{(1,n−p)}$.

Comment: I cannot believe this is not a duplicate, and yet all the upvotes (both on the question and the answers)... What about [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117406/proof-that-the-coefficients-in-an-ols-model-follow-a-t-distribution-with-n-k-d)? Or perhaps it is not a duplicate, which means there are (or there was until today) super-basic topics still that have not been covered over the nearly seven years of existence of Cross Validated... Wow...

Comment: @RichardHardy Hmm, that sounds like a duplicate. While it's more verbose, the question is specifically:
_"How can I prove that for $\hat\beta_i$,
$\frac{\hat{\beta}_i - \beta_i} {s_{\hat{\beta}_i}} \sim t_{n-k}$"_

Answer (score 43, accepted):

To understand why we use the t-distribution, you need to know what is the underlying distribution of $\widehat{\beta}$ and of the Residual sum of squares ($RSS$) as these two put together will give you the t-distribution.

The easier part is the distribution of $\widehat{\beta}$ which is a normal distribution - to see this note that $\widehat{\beta}$=$(X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}Y$ so it is a linear function of $Y$ where $Y\sim N(X\beta, \sigma^{2}I_{n})$. As a result it is also normally distributed, $\widehat{\beta} \sim N(\beta, \sigma^{2}(X^{T}X)^{-1})$ - let me know if you need help deriving the distribution of $\widehat{\beta}$.

Additionally, $RSS \sim \sigma^{2}\chi^{2}_{n-p}$, where $n$ is the number of observations and $p$ is the number of parameters used in your regression. The proof of this is a bit more involved, but also straightforward to derive (see proof here [Why is RSS distributed chi square times n-p?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20227/why-is-rss-distributed-chi-square-times-n-p)).

Up until this point I have considered everything in matrix/vector notation, but let's for simplicity use $\widehat{\beta}_{i}$ and use its normal distribution which will give us:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\widehat{\beta}_{i}-\beta_{i}}{\sigma\sqrt{(X^{T}X)^{-1}_{ii}}} \sim N(0,1)
\end{equation}

Additionally, from the chi-squared distribution of $RSS$ we have that:
\begin{equation}
\frac{(n-p)s^{2}}{\sigma^{2}} \sim \chi^{2}_{n-p}
\end{equation}

This was simply a rearrangement of the first chi-squared expression and is independent of the $N(0,1)$. Additionally, we define $s^{2}=\frac{RSS}{n-p}$, which is an unbiased estimator for $\sigma^{2}$. By the definition of the $t_{n-p}$ definition that dividing a normal distribution by an independent chi-squared (over its degrees of freedom) gives you a t-distribution (for the proof see: [A normal divided by the $\sqrt{\chi^2(s)/s}$ gives you a t-distribution -- proof](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/151854/a-normal-divided-by-the-sqrt-chi2s-s-gives-you-a-t-distribution-proof)) you get that:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\widehat{\beta}_{i}-\beta_{i}}{s\sqrt{(X^{T}X)^{-1}_{ii}}} \sim t_{n-p}
\end{equation}

Where $s\sqrt{(X^{T}X)^{-1}_{ii}}=SE(\widehat{\beta}_{i})$.

Let me know if it makes sense.

Comment: what a great answer! could you please explain why \begin{equation}
\frac{\widehat{\beta}_{i}-\beta_{i}}{\sigma\sqrt{(X^{T}X)^{-1}_{ii}}} \sim N(0,1)
\end{equation}?

Comment: it is nothing but normalization, e.g., $ \frac{\bar{x} - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}$. francium87d already gave the distribution of $\beta$s.

Answer (score 7):

The answer is actually very simple: you use t-distribution because it was pretty much designed specifically for this purpose.

Ok, the nuance here is that it wasn't designed specifically for the linear regression. [Gosset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Sealy_Gosset) came up with distribution of sample that was drawn from the population. For instance, you draw a sample $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$, and calculate its mean $\bar x=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i/n$. What is the distribution of a sample mean $\bar x$?

If you knew the true (population) standard deviation $\sigma$, then you'd say that the variable $\xi=(\bar x-\mu)\sqrt n/\sigma$ is from the standard normal distribution $\mathcal N(0,1)$. The trouble's that you usually do not know $\sigma$, and can only estimate it $\hat\sigma$. So, Gosset figured out the distribution when you substitute $\sigma$ with $\hat\sigma$ in the denominator, and the distribution is now called after his pseduonym "Student t".

The technicalities of linear regression lead to a situation where we can estimate the standard error $\hat\sigma_\beta$ of the coefficient estimate $\hat\beta$, but we do not know the true $\sigma$, therefore Student t distribution is applied here too.