# How to find $\mathbb{E} \left[\frac{\bar{\mu}}{\bar{\sigma}^2}\right]$?

Tags: probability, distributions, variance, expected-value, probability-inequalities

I asked the same question on math stacks: [MathStacks:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4837581/how-to-find-mathbbe-left-frac-bar-mu-bar-sigma2-right), and some user suggest to ask it here for better insight. So this question has found interest in many research problems, but there have been no concrete findings. I want to pose this questions here and take some feedback on how we can solve it. So lets assume you have a Gaussian distribution $X\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$, with $\mu\geq 0$. Let $$\bar{\mu} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$$ be the sample mean of $X$, and let $$\bar{\sigma}^2 = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{\mu})^2$$ be its biased estimator (you can assume unbiased estimator too). So now I want to find  $$\mathbb{E} \left[\frac{\bar{\mu}}{\bar{\sigma}^2}\right],$$ i.e. the expectation of sample mean to sample variance. If this is not achievable then then a concentration inequality on $$\mathbb{P} \left(\frac{\bar{\mu}}{\bar{\sigma}^2} - \frac{\mu}{\sigma^2} >\epsilon\right)$$
My solutions have not found anything solid and I don't think my ways are viable. Anyone who can give any hints on how to solve it would be appreciated.

PS: One user suggested to see t-distribution, but to use it we need the knowledge of mean.

Comment: Hint: $\bar\mu$ and $\bar\sigma^2$ are independent, and their distribution is known.

Comment: The sample variance estimate depend on $\bar{\mu}$, can we still say they are independent?

Comment: Yes. It is more generally true that the least-squares estimate of the mean and the residuals are independent in any Gaussian linear model.

Comment: Presumably your $\bar \mu$ is really $\hat \mu=\bar x =\frac{1}{n}\sum x_i$ and similarly $\bar \sigma^2$ is really $\hat \sigma^2$

Comment: Yes they are, I have edited my question

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117406/proof-that-the-coefficients-in-an-ols-model-follow-a-t-distribution-with-n-k-d?noredirect=1&lq=1 or https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20227/why-is-rss-distributed-chi-square-times-n-p?rq=1=?